# How to avoid repeat a noun that is mentioned previously

Tags: pronouns

In this sentence: The birth rate in the USA was higher than the birth rate in China.
If I wanna replace "the birth rate" before "in China", I would use "that" or "one"? 
Actually, I have already referred to some sample essays, the authors always use "that", but I do not know why they do not use "one"?
Thank you so much!

Comment: The USA birth rate was higher than China's.

Comment: That's what pronouns are for. You can replace *the birth rate* with *it was*. Or you could actually remove *the birth rate* altogether and the sentence would still be understandable. (And please don't write *wanna*; write *want to* instead.)

Answer (score 1):

To keep your sentence structured the same way, the best wording would be: **The birth rate in the USA was higher than *that* in China.**

Using the word *one* instead of *that* could be confusing or misleading. A country can only have a single birth rate. Using the word *one* makes is sound like China could have multiple birth rates at the same time.